# Power BI: Inserting both year and month in line chart legend

Tags: powerbi

I have a line chart in powerBI with the last 6 months as a legend (Sep,2020 - Feb,2021). The issue is that I want to have the months sorted by year (Sep-2020, Oct-2020....Jan-2021, Feb2021) but I can't insert both year and month in the legend and it accepts only one of them:

[image]
[image]

I have tried to make a new column in the edit query section that extracts the value (year-month) from the "Create_date" date column. But when I insert this column in the legend it takes all the values from all of my data, and not the last 6 months. The date filter I have is for the original "create_date" column.

[image]

Comment: Can you not show something like `2020-09 Sept`, `2020-10 Oct` ... `2021-03 Mar`
This way it will auto sort

Comment: @Rippo .. Actually this is the issue, I want to sort them based on year, then month. I am not sure I got your point well.

Comment: Ah sorry create a new column in power BI that computes the legend for you. Will post below as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to add a new column via the `Power Query Editor` that computes the legend for you. There maybe another funky way but this is how I would approach it.

The column has the following function

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Content", "Date For Legend", 
  each Number.ToText(Date.Year([Timestamp])) & 
       "-" & 
       Text.PadStart(Number.ToText(Date.Month([Timestamp])), 2, "0") & 
       " " & 
       Date.MonthName([Timestamp])
  )
```

This basically take my column called `[Tmestamp]` and formats it to a string field for my legend use. Note as `2020-09` comes before `2021-01` everything is in order.

[image: Power BI]

and then change the legend value on the line chart to `Date For Legend`

[image]
[image]